# MpLab C, Assembly, Interrupt defined conflicts

Tags: c, assembly, integration, pic24

I am placing some new C software routines together with an existing arrangement of assembly language.

I am finding these errors

```
    multiple definition of `_U1RXInterrupt'
    multiple definition of `_U2RXInterrupt'
    multiple definition of `_U3RXInterrupt'
```

Where, when, how, do I get the C compiler to let me have the `U1RXInterrupt` for my assembly routines ? Ditto for `U2RXInterrupt`

Update, 2013-MAR-13

Just found this in the C code. Is this the source of my problems ? IF I take take this away, will my conflicts be over ?

```
   //********************U1RX interrupt********************************//
   void __attribute__ ((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _U1RXInterrupt(void) 
   {
    IFS0bits.U1RXIF = 0;
    U1Buf_RX=U1RXREG;
    //putcharUART2(U1Buf_RX);
   }
```

I want my assembly language routines to handle Uart 1

I'm guessing that I will find a similar handler for U2RXInterrupt(void)

Comment: These are probably defined by the library of assembly code, not the compiler. Look in the library and see if the functions are there. If so, see if they have some kind of "hook" you could put your ISR in.

Comment: Where do I find the library ? Does it have a name ? What does it look like ?

Comment: Uh, it's whatever your "existing arrangement of assembly language" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only define one subroutine for a given interrupt. Whatever an ISR is defined through C code or assembler, it must be unique in your application.

So if you want to use your assembler ISR, you must either remove the other one from the C code or not link your application with the object or library that brings it.